# npm install errors

Tags: theming, 8

I'm having difficulties with setting up Drupal 8 and `Bootstrap SASS` (sandbox project).

When following the documentation for setting up Bootstrap SASS at https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/wrender/2627564, when I reach point #2, "run npm install" I get lots of errors and can't proceed.

*My versions*

- Mac OS X 10.11.6
- node v0.12.7
- ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

*Terminal output*

➜  bootstrap_sass git:(master) npm install

> bootstrap_starter_theme@1.0.0 postinstall /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass
>   find node_modules/ -name '*.info' -type f -delete
>
> npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/grunt requires minimatch@'~0.2.12' but will load
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/minimatch
>   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.2
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps requires strip-bom@'^2.0.0' but will load
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/strip-bom
>   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.0
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/gulp-watch requires vinyl@'^0.5.0' but will load
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/vinyl
>   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.1
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/gulp requires vinyl-fs@'^0.3.0' but will load
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/vinyl-fs
>   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.4.3
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/object-assign
>   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.1.0
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/gulp-util requires vinyl@'^0.5.0' but will load
>   npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/chandeepkhosa/w/pantheon/my-website/themes/bootstrap_sass/node_modules/vinyl
>   npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.1
>
> ```
> gulp-autoprefixer@2.3.1 node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer
> ├── object-assign@2.1.1
> ├── through2@0.6.5 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@1.0.34)
> ├── vinyl-sourcemaps-apply@0.1.4 (source-map@0.1.43)
> ├── postcss@4.1.16 (js-base64@2.1.9, source-map@0.4.4, es6-promise@2.3.0)
> └── autoprefixer-core@5.2.1 (num2fraction@1.2.2, browserslist@0.4.0, caniuse-db@1.0.30000518)
> ```

Comment: The link for the sandbox project is broken. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Thank you, yes the link is correct, but since posting this the sandbox maintainer deleted it as it is no longer relevant due to a SASS starterkit being included as part of Bootstrap project itself last week.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by updating my versions of NPM & Node to match the requirements stated on the project page (silly me).

Comment: You're not silly, that suff should be in the package.json under engines.